# How to set Angular model field, which has another model as data type

Tags: angular, api, http

There's a model called category and a model called booking. Booking has a field of type Category:

```
export interface Category {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}

export interface Booking {
  id: number;
  value: number;
  category: Category;
  date: Date;
}
```

The data for a booking will be set through input fields.

HTML:

```
  <form #addBookingForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="createBooking(addBookingForm)">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="value">Value of booking:</label><br>
      <input type="text" ngModel name="value" class="form-control" id="value">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
          <label for="category" class="input-group-text">Category</label>
        </div>
        <select type="text" ngModel name="category" class="custom-select" id="category">
          <option selected>select...</option>
          <option value="1">Gift</option>
          <option value="2">Income</option>
          <option value="3">Bill</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
    </div>
  </form>
```

TypeScript:

```
  public createBooking(addBookingForm: NgForm) {
    this.bookingService.addBooking(addBookingForm.value).subscribe(
      (response: Booking) => {
        console.log(response);
      },
      (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        alert(error.message);
      }
    )
  }
```

This results in the following HTTP-request payload:

```
{value: "45.0", category: "2"}
category: "2"
value: "45.0"
```

The error response is 500 internal server error, because the category field isn't set correctly with the input fields I've created. I'd appreciate any recommendations.

**EDIT**

I turned the option input into category objects and the payload changed accordingly, but the category object has no detailed definition:

```
{value: "45.0", category: "category"}
category: "category"
value: "45.0"
```

This JSON string works fine for testing the REST API, something like this for the HTML/TS file should work (maybe a HTTP request that sends a string in this format, but with dynamic values?):

```
{
  "value": "70.0",
  "category": {
    "id": 2
  },
  "date": "2022-08-04"
}
```

Comment: You need to make the select options an object of type `category`. Can you create a Stackblitz example that i can edit?

Comment: I did that and posted the current payload in the edit section @Rajat

Comment: can you create a stackblitz example?

Comment: I will create one and tell you, when it's done @Rajat

Comment: Your code is breaking, please fix it

Answer (score 1):

I think you can solve this by passing your complet category as value of the options like this:

```
  <select type="text" ngModel name="category" class="custom-select" id="category">
    <option selected>select...</option>
    <option *ngFor="let o of categoryOptions" [value]="o">{{o.name}}</option>
  </select>


  categoryOptions = [
    { id: 1, name: 'Test1' },
    { id: 2, name: 'Test2' },
    { id: 3, name: 'Test3' },
  ];
```

You also not have to pass your exact form object, you can map the date before sending over http.

```
public createBooking(addBookingForm: NgForm) {
    this.bookingService.addBooking({
        value: addBookingForm.value.value,
        category: {
            id: addBookingForm.value.categoryId,
        },
        date: "2022-06-06"
    }).subscribe(...)
}
```

Comment: I turned the options into objects, but I still get the same error. I think it's because the payload includes a category object, which is not defined furthermore now. You can take a look at my post, I'll edit the payload result

Comment: After the first approach didn't work, I had an idea about creating a dynamic string inside the request body. Please take a look at my edit section @Flo

Answer (score 0):

As @Flo and @Rajat already mentioned, the options have to be category objects.
This resulted in another issue though. The category name got set instead of the id.

[image]

The solution is to use ngValue instead of value and give it the category list item, while the iteration via *ngFor takes place:

```
<select type="text" ngModel name="category" class="custom-select" id="category">
      <option selected>select...</option>
      <option *ngFor="let category of categories" [ngValue]="category">{{category.name}}</option>
</select>
```